# Single touch detection in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c

First of all, I just want to say that I begin at Objective-C.

Here is the layout of my projet:
mainView > ScrollView inside mainView > ImageView inside ScrollView

Both of mainView and scrollView are created in Storyboard. All the imageView are created programmatically and as subview in scrollView.

I've only one class nammed ViewController.

Here is my question:
How can I handle single touch on ImageView inside my scrollView ? Let's me know if something is not clear.

UPDATE:

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ (%i).png", path, path, nbrImage];
            CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(40, 25 + (line*lenght), 75, 75);
            self.img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
            [self.img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagePath]];

            UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
            singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;     
            singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            [self.img addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];

            [self.scrollView addSubview:self.img];

- (void)handleSingleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

   UIImageView* imageView = (id)recognizer.view;
   NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

EDIT: that works, in @selector I've write handleSingleTap instead of handleSingleTapFrom:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a UIControl to your imageView to perform whatever selector you want in response to a single touch. Just set the background color to clear, the frame to imageView.frame, add the control as a subview of your imageView and say

```
[myControl addtarget:self action:@selector(whateverYouWantToDo) forControlEvents:UIConntrolEventTouchUpInside];
```

EDIT:

```
UIControl *myControl = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame]; 
[myControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
[myControl addTarget:self action:@selector(doWork) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[imageView addSubview:myControl];
```

then just implement the doWork method to do whatever you're trying to do. I may have misunderstood your question but if you want to perform an action when the user touches an image in your scroll view this is the way I've done it.

Comment: Have I to implement something like touchsBegin thereafter ? Can you just show an example ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes you understand my question. If the user touches Image1, I want display Image1 in mainView. I edited my original post

Comment: Also, here's a link to a tutorial that achieves what I think you're trying to do. http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). E.g.,

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)] autorelease];
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;     
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
```

With the handler method:

```
- (void)handleSingleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    UIImageView* imageView = (id)recognizer.view;
    ...
}
```

Comment: `[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)] autorelease];`
In this code, what is `handleSingleTape` ? A method that I have to implement ? Sorry if this a trivial question :s

Comment: You are right, see my edit or the reference for the signature.